# ansible --limit option succession

Tags: ansible, limit

I have a problem with application of my playbook in Ansible.

There is my inventory file /etc/ansible/developpement:

```
[vm]
[...]
host1.example.com iplan=10.0.220.37
host2.example.com iplan=10.0.220.38
[...]
```

I want to apply a config like that :

```
$ ansible-playbook /etc/ansible/playbooks/developpement.yml --inventory-file=/etc/ansible/developpement --diff --check --tags php5.6-fpm --limit host1.example.com
[...]
 pm = ondemand
-pm.max_children = 599
+pm.max_children = 600
 pm.start_servers = 50
 pm.min_spare_servers = 32
 pm.max_spare_servers = 150
[...]

changed: [host1.example.net]
```

There is only one host updated and this a normal behaviour.

Now, i'm trying to apply this same configuration with second host :

```
$ ansible-playbook /etc/ansible/playbooks/developpement.yml --inventory-file=/etc/ansible/developpement --diff --check --tags php5.6-fpm --limit host2.example.com
[...]
-env[DEVELOPER] = variable linked to host 1
+env[DEVELOPER] = host2
[...]
-env[DEVELOPER_EMAIL] = email linked to host 1
+env[DEVELOPER_EMAIL] = host2@example.net
[...]



 pm.status_path = /status
 ; host-specific php ini settings here

changed: [host1.bazarchic.com]
```

ansible-playbook put host 1 variables into the result of the second request, i don't understand why.

I tried to try without --check, the variables linked to host1 are set to the second host.

I had not the probleme with 2.2 version of Ansible.

Version : **ansible 2.6.0**

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

File : /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg

```
[defaults]
inventory      = /etc/ansible/hosts
host_key_checking = True
gather_timeout = 30
timeout = 20
log_path = /var/log/ansible.log
system_warnings = True
 deprecation_warnings = True
retry_files_enabled = False
[privilege_escalation]
[paramiko_connection]
[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o ForwardAgent=yes -o ConnectTimeout=30 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ControlPath=/dev/shm/cp%%h-%%p-%%r
[accelerate]
[selinux]
[colors]
```

Comment: not sure if it matters too much but if it is providing a problem you are spelling `development` wrong. `developpement` --> `development`

Comment: Yes, you're right, developpement is the french word

Comment: Ahh I see, I thought the difference in spellings could have been a problem as well. mb @nicolas

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.

In the ansible.cfg this is my SSH options connection :

```
ssh_args = -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o ForwardAgent=yes -o ConnectTimeout=30 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ControlPath=/dev/shm/cp%%h-%%p-%%r
```

I deleted the "ControlPath" option and it works.

In my opinion, this option is useless for the ansible 2.3